# Java not getting values held in array

Tags: java, netbeans

```
if(itemID < 0){
                //add total
                totalAmount = totalAmount + itemCosts[itemID - 1];
                //increment counter
                itemCounter++;
            }
```

In this chunk of code I am trying to iterate through my loop after asking the customer to enter numbers corresponding to elements in my array. But I am not getting the values out of the array and into the total amount which I am trying to display at the end of my code.

Comment: A negative value, and then subtracting 1, is likely to not be a valid array index.

Comment: Exactly.  If you're even entering this code there should be an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` being thrown.  If you're not seeing that, you're not in this code block.

Comment: Did you perhaps intent to write `if (itemID > 0)` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I see a big problem right here:

```
if(itemID < 0)
```

and right here:

```
 itemCosts[itemID - 1]
```

Every value of itemID must be negative for this conditional to run, you then pass a negative value in for an array index.  Java does not support using negative indexes on arrays.  You may need to flip your conditional, if thats what you inteded to be:

```
if(itemID > 0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much you are a life saver. I knew it was just a logical error but I could not see it!